# Hibernate on Glassfish not an entity exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have the following problem:
The application is deployed successfully, but whenever i try to execute a query it ends up like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class javaeetutorial.addressbook.entity.Contact
```

So here are my configs:

**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="address-bookPU" transaction-type="JTA">

<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/PostgreSQLDataSource</jta-data-source>

<class>javaeetutorial.addressbook.entity.Contact</class>

<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
  <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The entity class is annotated with *@Entity* of course.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Is it annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity`?

Comment: Yes it is. I have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: Okay, downgrading from hibernate version: 4.3.6.Final to 4.3.0.Final seems to be a solution(?). Has anyone got an idea what can be going on?

Comment: can you post the code for your Entity?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qVG8EfcA
It's from the java ee tutorial
@Cache has been added since then (not a part of the problem)

Answer (score 0):

I spent two days and found the following solution.
1. Use at least Hibernate 4.3.10:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Change persistence.xml as follows (schema 2.1, provider
`<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`, two properties - a MUST):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="your_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/your_src</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm, jar"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```